# replace all germanumlauts

Tags: php

I used this `str_replace` to rename `ü` to `ue`:

```
$headline = "für";
echo str_replace('ü','ue',$headline); // will output fuer
```

Now, what if there is **ö**, **ä** & **ß**. I need to convert those to oe, ae, ss respectively. Can I use `preg_replace`? If yes, how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use arrays in `str_replace`

```
str_replace(array('ü','ö'),array('ue',''),$headline);
```

If everything needs be replaced by the same character, just remove the `array` from `replace` and keep it as `ue`.

Add your replacements to both arrays correctly, and it should work fine!

Comment: Didn't thought and see that.